# Reprojection of a raster window in rasterio

Tags: python, coordinate-system, rasterio

I'm working with the [ETOPO global relief model](https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/products/etopo-global-relief-model), trying to take samples centred at different longitudes and latitudes and reproject them into a locally flat coordinate system. I'm trying to do this by reprojecting into an equidistant cylindrical system centred on the desired coordinates. Here's the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import rasterio
from rasterio import warp
from rasterio.warp import calculate_default_transform,reproject,Resampling
from rasterio import windows

lat = 52.0; long = 0.0
swatch_size_m = 2.e6 # in metres
custom_crs = {"proj":"eqc",
              "lat_ts":lat,"lat_0":lat,"lon_0":long,
              "x_0":0,"y_0":0,
              "datum":"WGS84",
              "units":"m",
              "no_defs":True,
              "over":True}

src = rasterio.open("data/ETOPO_2022_v1_30s_N90W180_bed.tif")

my_crs = rasterio.CRS.from_dict(custom_crs)
src_crs = src.crs

bot_r,left_r,top_r,right_r = warp.transform_bounds(my_crs,src_crs,
                                                   -swatch_size_m/2,-swatch_size_m/2,
                                                   swatch_size_m/2,swatch_size_m/2,
                                                   2.0)
# For some reason, this gives the correct values but in radians. 
# Seems to be because src_crs.units_factor specifies conversion from degrees to radians.  
left = left_r*180/np.pi
bottom = bot_r*180/np.pi
right = right_r*180/np.pi
top = top_r*180/np.pi

window = src.window(left,bottom,right,top)
src_transform = src.window_transform(window)

with rasterio.open("data/ETOPO_2022_v1_30s_N90W180_bed.tif") as src:
    wdata = src.read(1,window=window)
plt.imshow(wdata,cmap="binary") # This looks correct - a window approximately centred on London

# This is where the code seems to go wrong...
transform, width, height = calculate_default_transform(
        src_crs, my_crs, window.width, window.height, 
        left=left_r,bottom=bot_r,right=right_r,top=top_r)

wdest = np.zeros((height,width),dtype=wdata.dtype)

_,_ = reproject(
    source=wdata,
    destination=wdest,
    src_transform=src_transform,
    src_crs=src_crs,
    dst_transform=transform,
    dst_crs=custom_crs,
    resampling=Resampling.bilinear
)
```

This just produces an empty array. `transform` also doesn't look quite right, neither do `width` and `height`: I'd expect them all to be commensurate with the initial window shape. If I use `warp.transform_bounds` in the inverse to how it's called here, it does reproduce the correct bounds - so I'm lost as to why `reproject` doesn't.